# Archive Button in Outlook for Mac Not Showing on Ribbon

Tags: ms-office

According to the [Outlook UserVoice site](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/293343-outlook-for-mac/suggestions/8866420-ability-to-replace-delete-button-with-archive), the latest version of Outlook for Mac has an Archive feature.

Based on this Microsoft article there [supposed to be an Archive button](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Archive-messages-in-Outlook-for-Mac-10a5f3f2-1c50-4477-af19-034f09289655) next to the Delete button on the ribbon.

I'm running Microsoft Outlook for Mac Version 15.24 and I'm not seeing the new button. I'm I running the right version? What do I need to do to make the Archive button show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the Archive button showed up when I added a Google account to Outlook for Mac. It did not show for the existing Exchange account. Guess the archive feature doesn't work with Exchange.

Comment: Ugh.  Outlook sucks.  I have been looking for that button!